# Angular Typescript map the elements of array to the class object (attributes) or create an object based on array elements?

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

I am using:

Angular CLI: 10.0.6

Node: 12.18.2

OS: win32 x6

Angular: 10.0.10

I am having a method to get the selected rows from ag-grid.

Returned value:

[image]

This is one row. Now I have a class corresponding to this array elements i.e. 22 attributes. I want to map this array (row) to its attributes.

e.g.

```
export class Summary {

  constructor(
    public date: Date,
    public name: string,
    public myNum: string,
    public entity: string,
    // other attributes 
  ) {

  }
}
```

Basically, this has exact attributes as row returned (as the row is of this object).

I need to convert the array row to Summary object, so I can send it as a Http request (Rest API accepts the List as request object).

How to do this?

Comment: Having complete control over the order of the parameters in each array, the most simple way is to assign one by one `{par1: arr[0], par2: arr[1], ...}`. Alternatively, build up an array with the attributes name in the right order and iterate through them to the end, collecting the values in the equivalent index positions in the values arrays. I'm supposing you're doing this one time only. If this is spread all over the app, maybe the server could send you the array of attributes names in the right order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like this:

column index needs to always represent the same field

class

```
export class Summary {
  
    public date: Date;
    public name: string;
    public myNum: string;
    public entity: string;
    ...

  constructor(args:any[]) {
    this.date = args[0];
    this.name = args[1];
    ...
  }
}
```

in ts

```
const summary = new Summary(row)
```